# Does nefness carry over through flips?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry, minimal-model-program

Suppose $\pi: X \dashrightarrow Y$ is a birational map which is an isomorphism in codimension 1 (such as a flip). Also suppose both $X$ and $Y$ have reasonable (say log terminal) singularities. We know  that divisors in $X$ and $Y$ correspond bijectively to each other.  If $D$ is a nef divisor in $X$, is it true that $\overline{\pi(D)}$ is also nef in $Y$?

Comment: No, $\overline{\pi(D)}$ will typically have a non-empty base locus where it is negative - try to see what happens in the Atiyah flop..

Comment: More precisely, for a klt flip, it carries through iff $D\cdot \Sigma =0$ where $\Sigma$ is the flipping curve (else $D\cdot \Sigma >0$ and so $\overline{\pi(D)} \cdot \Sigma ^+<0$ where $\Sigma ^+$ is a flipped curve....if $D\cdot \Sigma=0$, use the base point free thm). This fact is important when running the mmp with scaling.